# Does Skywrath Mage Ulti stack?

Tags: dota-2

Skywrath Mage has a heavy damage ultimate, and after reaching level 16 its damage is further increased to 1400. If  Aganhim's Scepter  is purchased for him, his ultimate's cooldown reduces to 0. With this in mind, if 2 ultimates are used on the same hero, will the ultimates stack?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it stacks. However you will need a huge manapool (or an [Obsidian Destroyer](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Outworld_Devourer#Essence_Aura)) because this built is really mana intensive.

Comment: If you have level 3 ultimate and aghanim scepter does OD aura works as there is no cooldown? I mean obviously it works on his other spells but I'm not sure about the ulti

Comment: @T_O I was think replenish your mana with arcane bolt (70 mana on a 2 sec CD). I don't know for the 0 sec CD ult but I assume it does. Gotta test though

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. Essence Aura is confirmed to not proc on any spell with a zero second cooldown, barring OD's orb.

Comment: @Kenneth Toggling vodoo restauration triggers essence aura, any thought ?

Comment: Yeah, those are meant to be fixed. That includes Ball Lightning as well. The playdota site specifies that skills with no cooldown don't proc it.

Comment: @WizLiz Now I really want to know if it triggers OD aura. Logically you'd only need 2000 mana 'on average', but that doesn't cut it, but more realistically 2400 or 3200.

Answer (score 1):

You can see here that DPS **does stack up**.

But in practical games it doesn't end up so effective,unless you are snowballing crazily and have some serious disable in your team.

It's just too hard to farm up items that give you **enough mana to pull this off**,and once you do enemies will be too tanky,will kill you too fast or won't be disabled for long enough.

Comment: oh,and good luck trying this against pugna :p

Comment: Blademail and BKB :D

Comment: Sure,but imagine the reactions of the polite dota teammates to a skywrath with blademail and BKB xD

Comment: Touché. Though I assume that if you can build an aghanim and enough mana to spam your ulti... at that you can have a bkb and a blade mail ^_^.